# Access Query Designer Woes -- select by multiple values not working

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

- Table 1 Names
- Table 2 Services

If I do a simple select of both tables together, I get a list as follows:

- Name1 Service X
- Name2 Service X
- Name2 Service X
- Name2 Service Y
- Name3 Service Y
- Name3 Service X

I would like to limit the list to only people who have Service X AND Y, one return per name (distinct select).

Comment: Whoops, looks like my example table got squished. :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Giving them a pivot table of the data in excel. I find it a lot more comfortable and friendly than Access. Bleh. SSRS reports make more sense to build than Access. I'll still need to build something more automatic if they plan on seeing this updated with any frequency. Might just directly update Excel from the Access connection and not poke around inside anymore.

Comment: Please include the actual queries you are using.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is to count how many distinct X or Y services a user has, and then return only those that have two (i.e. - both):

```
SELECT   n.name
FROM     names n
JOIN     services s ON n.user_id = s.user_id
WHERE    s.name IN ('X', 'Y'Y)
GROUP BY names.name
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT s.name) = 2
```